# Woocommerce/WordPress and ACID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, transactions, acid

As I understand it WordPress does not use transactions when querying the database. After looking at the Woocommerce source code it looks like Woocommerce does not either. One of my questions is: how can an application built to handle monetary transactions (orders and payments) not rely on ACID? Running without transactions renders isolation levels useless, or does it not? Opening up for all kinds of misbehaviour in the application (*dirty reads/writes, read/write skew, phantom reads*).

I want to dissect a section of the create order function in Woocommerce and maybe someone out there can shed some light on how Woocommerce can handle several thousands of order transactions per minute reliably without ACID.

> Sky is the limit. We’ve seen instances of shops with 100,000+ products listed, handling thousands of transactions per minute. In those cases, they had great hosting support and their own developer team focused on optimization.

source: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-scaling-faqs/

**From now on I will paste code below to help illustrate my thought process but refer to line numbers from the actual sources (linked). Each source will be given a name. Thank you.**

Let's look at a simple example where Woocommerce updates several post_meta in a loop.

It all begins in the **create()** function.

```
/**
 * Method to create a new order in the database.
 *
 * @param WC_Order $order Order object.
 */
public function create( &$order ) {
    $order->set_version( Constants::get_constant( 'WC_VERSION' ) );
    $order->set_currency( $order->get_currency() ? $order->get_currency() : get_woocommerce_currency() );
    if ( ! $order->get_date_created( 'edit' ) ) {
        $order->set_date_created( time() );
    }

    $id = wp_insert_post(
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_new_order_data',
            array(
                'post_date'     => gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $order->get_date_created( 'edit' )->getOffsetTimestamp() ),
                'post_date_gmt' => gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $order->get_date_created( 'edit' )->getTimestamp() ),
                'post_type'     => $order->get_type( 'edit' ),
                'post_status'   => $this->get_post_status( $order ),
                'ping_status'   => 'closed',
                'post_author'   => 1,
                'post_title'    => $this->get_post_title(),
                'post_password' => $this->get_order_key( $order ),
                'post_parent'   => $order->get_parent_id( 'edit' ),
                'post_excerpt'  => $this->get_post_excerpt( $order ),
            )
        ),
        true
    );

    if ( $id && ! is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
        $order->set_id( $id );
        $this->update_post_meta( $order );
        $order->save_meta_data();
        $order->apply_changes();
        $this->clear_caches( $order );
    }
}
```

SOURCE1: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-abstract-wc-order-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.58

On line 86 (SOURCE1) we call `$this->update_post_meta( $order );` and I assume that it is called to update the post_meta table in the database. This is the function:

```
/**
 * Helper method that updates all the post meta for an order based on it's settings in the WC_Order class.
 *
 * @param WC_Order $order Order object.
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
protected function update_post_meta( &$order ) {
    $updated_props     = array();
    $meta_key_to_props = array(
        '_order_currency'     => 'currency',
        '_cart_discount'      => 'discount_total',
        '_cart_discount_tax'  => 'discount_tax',
        '_order_shipping'     => 'shipping_total',
        '_order_shipping_tax' => 'shipping_tax',
        '_order_tax'          => 'cart_tax',
        '_order_total'        => 'total',
        '_order_version'      => 'version',
        '_prices_include_tax' => 'prices_include_tax',
    );

    $props_to_update = $this->get_props_to_update( $order, $meta_key_to_props );

    foreach ( $props_to_update as $meta_key => $prop ) {
        $value = $order->{"get_$prop"}( 'edit' );
        $value = is_string( $value ) ? wp_slash( $value ) : $value;

        if ( 'prices_include_tax' === $prop ) {
            $value = $value ? 'yes' : 'no';
        }

        $updated = $this->update_or_delete_post_meta( $order, $meta_key, $value );

        if ( $updated ) {
            $updated_props[] = $prop;
        }
    }

    do_action( 'woocommerce_order_object_updated_props', $order, $updated_props );
}
```

SOURCE2: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-abstract-wc-order-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.318

Ok, on line 334 (SOURCE2) we run a loop meaning that we will call function `$this->update_or_delete_post_meta( $order, $meta_key, $value );` on line 342 (SOURCE2) for each meta value we want to update. Ok, that function looks like this:

```
/**
 * Update meta data in, or delete it from, the database.
 *
 * Avoids storing meta when it's either an empty string or empty array.
 * Other empty values such as numeric 0 and null should still be stored.
 * Data-stores can force meta to exist using `must_exist_meta_keys`.
 *
 * Note: WordPress `get_metadata` function returns an empty string when meta data does not exist.
 *
 * @param WC_Data $object The WP_Data object (WC_Coupon for coupons, etc).
 * @param string  $meta_key Meta key to update.
 * @param mixed   $meta_value Value to save.
 *
 * @since 3.6.0 Added to prevent empty meta being stored unless required.
 *
 * @return bool True if updated/deleted.
 */
protected function update_or_delete_post_meta( $object, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    if ( in_array( $meta_value, array( array(), '' ), true ) && ! in_array( $meta_key, $this->must_exist_meta_keys, true ) ) {
        $updated = delete_post_meta( $object->get_id(), $meta_key );
    } else {
        $updated = update_post_meta( $object->get_id(), $meta_key, $meta_value );
    }

    return (bool) $updated;
}
```

SOURCE3: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-data-store-wp.html#source-view.250

We can see that the actual update happens on row 254 (SOURCE3), when calling what I presume to be WordPress´ native `update_post_meta( $object->get_id(), $meta_key, $meta_value );` function.

**So this is my concern.** What happens if **any** update on row 254 (SOURCE3) fails and the entire order creation needs to be rolled back? We previously entered a row into the post table on row 65 (SOURCE1). Does that row not need to be deleted if one of the updates of post_meta fails, leaving us with a corrupt order in the database? I cant figure out if the function calls on rows 87 (SOURCE1) and 88 (SOURCE1) validates the outcome of the order creation in any way, and if they work as some kind of `COMMIT/ROLLBACK`? There is not even validation/error handling on the return of the function calls on rows 86 (SOURCE1), 87 (SOURCE1), 88 (SOURCE1). How do we know if anything has failed at all?

Further more, how does WordPress/Woocommerce handle reading/writing from the database when reads and writes can affect each other (*dirty/skew/phantom reads/writes*) when no locking can occur because there are no transactions?

Anyone?

Many thanks!!

Comment: The nature of WordPress’s hook and plugin system would make database transactions hard, which is why at a high level they aren’t explicitly supported. At a lower level, however, there really isn’t much that can fail, or if it did fail, everything else would fail, too. There are no foreign keys, triggers, constraints, etc. that could cause an insert to fail, and WordPress more often than not stores complex data as giant serialized strings, so it is more likely that the application will have an exception, rather than the database.

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea that hooks and plugins are the reason why there are no transactions. But not really clarifying anything in this case. In the example I brought up the information is not stored as a serializable string, but rather as individual rows in tables. I can give another example. Let's pretend that we are developing a room booking app. To guarantee that the same room does not get booked twice at the same time we are forced to work with serializable isolation. How would a similar business rule be implemented in WordPress?

Comment: So there’s WordPress, Woo and “the rest”. Woo is a WP plugin, currently owned by WP, and is meant to be extensible, so it follows WP patterns which means that generally speaking, mission-critical things are done in application logic, not database-level constraints. Once you get to that need, which many businesses don’t need*, you get into “other”, and that’s where you decide if WP and/or Woo are a good fit. WP doesn’t stop you from using transactions, they are in fact very easy to add, they just don’t have active support for it.

Comment: To your specific scenario, I’m skipping Woo and only thinking about WordPress, I think you’ll run into the same problem everyone runs into. Does “hearting” a room remove it from inventory? How about “buy now”, knowing that the person is actually adding it to their cart to see the final price to show someone else. Or, is it not until you hit the CC stage, which might require a third party redirect and thus the current process and transaction ending. Basically, we’re talking application-level validation versus infrastructure enforcement.

Comment: Ok, let me ask you this: Would it be beneficial from a performance perspective to set READ UNCOMMITTED as the isolation level when working with WordPress? My understanding is that BASE equals the isolation level READ UNCOMMITTED? And when working with WordPress READ UNCOMMITTED should have no impact on the application at all. Thoughts? I guess I need to look more into how and why hooks and plugins break transactions. And how the DB locking mechanism is transferred to the application (meta locking in WordPress' case).

Comment: WordPress itself might not use transactions, but other plugins might (but probably not), so make sure you test with any of those plugins in mind. There isn’t “application meta locking”, just application-level validation such as “insert row, did that work? okay, insert more rows”. If a post is written to DB, followed by two post meta inserts, and the second one fails, a WP_Error is generated, and yes, that post will have missing data. The database will still be consistent, although the data won’t be correct from the application standpoint.

Comment: To wrap this up, WordPress is giant abstraction over many complicated things. If you want to use the abstraction in all its simplicity, you have to accept that certain “best practices” are thrown out the window. Things like ACID, normalization or even data types. (Seriously, beyond the core fields, everything custom gets stored as a string.) WordPress runs everywhere, but it was built for lowest common denominator shared hosting in an era where MySQL might not even support transactions for a given storage engine.